# Install mosh on vyatta

Tags: networking, package-management

I'd like to install [mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/) on a [vyatta](http://www.vyatta.com/) machine.

Unfortunately vyatta does not have it pre-packaged. It does not even have gcc installed and I don't know if the required dependencies are available.

Maybe I could just get the deb package from another repository (vyatta supports apt-get) but I don't know if it is possible nor if it is a good idea at all.

I added the

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free repository
```

repository but I get dependencies issues:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mosh: Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.3.1-9 is to be installed
    Depends: libtinfo5 but it is not going to be installed
    Depends: libio-pty-perl but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue by simply commenting out the original vyatta repository, leaving only debian's one.

Beware, I am not an expert of linux packaging systems and I don't know whether it was a good idea, however it worked for me.